# Why do methods that return objects have an asterisk in the brackets?

Tags: objective-c

Why do methods that return objects have the asterisk in the brackets?

Example: `-(NSString *) method:val;`

Comment: Have a look at Apple's ["Programming with Objective-C"](http://developer.apple.com/library/mac/documentation/Cocoa/Conceptual/ProgrammingWithObjectiveC/Introduction/Introduction.html) documentation, in particular the section "Use Pointers to Keep Track of Objects".

Comment: Methods can't return objects because the object type doesn't exist in Objective-C.

Comment: PLEEEEASE learn about pointers before you try to do any more Objective-C programming!!!

Answer (score 0):

This is C notation - the return value is a pointer to NSString, not a local copy of said NSString. It is analogous (in fact I think it's the same implementation-wise) as returning a pointer to a struct instead of the struct directly.